# Generar consultas con eloquent o de manera nativa en laravel 5.8

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mysql

```
SELECT count.list_id, COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT list_id FROM vicidial_list 
WHERE list_id in (1000,2000,3000,4000) AND called_count = 0 AND status = 'NEW') 
as count
GROUP BY count.list_id;
```

Que necesito pasarla a Laravel bien sea por el ORM o por solo consulta pero por ORM no se como construirlo y por consulta lo genero de la siguiente manera

```
DB::connection('asterisk')
   ->select('SELECT count.list_id, COUNT(*) FROM (
            SELECT list_id FROM vicidial_list 
            WHERE list_id IN (?) AND called_count = 0 AND status = ?) as count
            GROUP BY count.list_id;',[1000,2000,3000,4000],0,'NEW');
```

Pero eso me devuelve un valor vacio, y si ejecuto la consulta por sql si me devuelve los valores que quiero.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tal cual lo estas haciendo no es correcto, Podrías intentar ejecutar toda tu consulta con `DB::raw()` y ver si te funciona.

Si no, intenta lo siguiente:

```
$sql = DB::table('vicidial_list')
        ->select('list_id')
        ->whereIn('list_id', [1000,2000,3000,4000])
        ->where('called_count', 0)
        ->where('status', 'NEW')->toSql();

$result = DB::table( DB::raw("($sql) as count") )
        ->select("count.list_id")
        ->selectRaw("COUNT(*)")
        ->groupBy('count.list_id')
        ->get();
```

Esto debería generar la siguiente consulta:

```
select `count`.`list_id`, COUNT(*) from (select `list_id` from `vicidial_list` where `list_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?) and `called_count` = ? and `status` = ?) as count group by `count`.`list_id`
```

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Y luego para pasarle los parametros que necesito como haría?